# SQL Cube(analysis Services) Consumption

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sdk, analysisservices

what tools or SDK available to consume the SQL cube(analysis services(SSAS)) through a .net service and interfaces and if possible with LINQ query ability ,

currently am using ADOMD.net but you need to use mdx as a query , is it possible to use LINQ in this sdk

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21209444. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.

Comment: thank you for your concern i appreciate it (since these comments don't belong here lets delete them after where done ) i have read the help article carefully actually , if you review the triage ,me and three other reviewers have voted for the need of edit and one voted to "Unsalvageable" so in my openion and the other three and from what i read from the question , i think its in need of more edit  .

Comment: putting aside the fact that the question is already voted down , so please fill me in on any other points that i might missed , thank you

Comment: more over to support my vote - "Rewrite the title to represent the core of the problem" , "Check" and he might as well edit the picture into an actual exception, so it might be salvageable after words  and might use a second chance . please do add any other thought i missed.

Answer (score 0):

[ADOMD.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/adomd-net/developing-with-adomd-net?view=sql-server-2017) is the one you are looking for. You can fetch data from the CUBE using MDX queries.

Comment: can i query using LINQ ?

Comment: It's supported to use LINQ to MDX. SSAS Entity Framework Provider enables you to use LINQ and Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework to query OLAP cubes, offline cube files and SSAS in-memory Tabular model (BISM) like a regular relational database.

Comment: Kickstart with this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/860143/Introduction-to-Percolator-Analysis-Services-LINQ

Comment: am using this tool already (Percolator) , its great and very useful but it have its limitations and its still under testing , for example i can't use multi where statement for the same field .

Comment: thats why am asking about SDKs